# Jira Python Keyerror on issue links

Tags: python-3.x, jira-rest-api, keyerror

I have a script which goes to fetch info via Jira API then its doing some comparison but i'm getting the following error :

Error : 
  "errorMessage": "'outwardIssue'"
  "errorType": "KeyError"

JSON format:

"issuelinks": [

```
{
    "id": "1255",
    "self": "https://jiraurl/rest/api/2/issueLink/0000",
    "type": {
        "id": "10030",
        "name": "Arises ",
        "inward": "gives rise to",
        "outward": "arises from",
        "self": "https://jiraurl/rest/api/2/issueLinkType/0000"
    },
    "outwardIssue": {
        "id": "1251575",
        "key": "temp-511",
        "self": "https://jiraurl/rest/api/2/issue/0000",
        "fields": {
            "summary": "a summary",
            "status": {
                "self": "https://jiraurl/rest/api/2/status/6",
                "description": "test",
                "iconUrl": "",
                "name": "Closed",
                "id": "6",
                "statusCategory": {
                    "self": "https://jiraurl/rest/api/2/statuscategory/3",
                    "id": 3,
                    "key": "done",
                    "colorName": "green",
                    "name": "Done"
                }
            },
            "issuetype": {
                "self": "https://jiraurl/rest/api/2/issuetype/20",
                "id": "20",
                "description": "Problem ",
                "iconUrl": "https://jiraurl/images/icons/issuetypes/documentation.png",
                "name": "Problem",
                "subtask": false
            }
        }
    }
}
```

]

Python Statement where we believe the issue is:

if (problem['fields']['issuelinks'][0]['outwardIssue']) and (problem['fields']['issuelinks'][0]['type']['outward'] == "arises from"):
                    isitanissue = False

I cant see why its stuck on'outwardIssue' ?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
issue = jira.issue("XX)

if (issue.raw['fields']['issuelinks'][0]['outwardIssue']) and (issue.raw['fields']['issuelinks'][0]['type']['outward'] == "arises from"): isitanissue = False
```